# jboss application server newbie question

Tags: java, jboss, application-server

I am starting to learn JBoss.
Went to the download page http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads.html but I can not understand what is the official version i.e. GA.
There is **7.0.0.Alpha1 6.0.0.CR1 6.0.0.M5 6.0.0.M4** etc
I am not sure what each version is about (What does M* or CR1 mean?)
Can someone help me please?
Which version should I download?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M` means a `milestone` - an important step which is achieved in a project. `CR` is `candidate release`. That means it is still not completely validated(it is not yet `GA`). Read [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProjectVersioning) for more detailed explanation.

You should download the latest milestone release in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you.The link says that final marks the GA release. But there is no final in the download page.Where do they post the final release?

Comment: @user384706 http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/downloads/JBOSSTS_4_13_1_Final. Here for JBoss Transactions they have written final. I think that for JBoss AS, they just don't write it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your post's timestamp, on the 5th of December you were asking right before the release of JBoss Application Server 6.0.0 on the 28th. In that time the AS6 range has progressed past the 6.1.0.Final release cycle, while AS7 has undertaken a rapid development cycle.

At the time of posting, you can download [JBoss Application Server 7.0.2.Final](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads), as well as 7.1.0.Beta1b, depending on how close to the cutting edge you would like to be. To make sense of the version codes and some of the [software release life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle):

- Final = a polished, tested, and approved version
- GA = General Availability, a final version preparing for the big time
- CR = a Candidate Release in the running for GA, undergoing final testing and QE
- M = a Milestone release, rolling features and bug fixes into a build
- ER = an Engineering Release, typically a build for the engineering team

All of these will differ from organisation to organisation, as the profiles for what each Milestone Release represent are subject to the flavour of project management. As an example, look at the [Meego Wiki](http://wiki.meego.com/Release_Engineering/Milestones) page for the explanation of their Milestone releases.

Answer (score 1):

The latest "official version" is 5.1.0.

If you are learning JBoss you might be better off with 6.0.0 CR1. As a release candidate it might not be quite as stable as an official 6.0.0 release, however you will be learning about the next version rather than the last one.

Comment: 5.1.0 does not have an indicator.So no indicator (i.e. CR,M) means GA in JBoss?

Comment: Yes, if you follow the link to download JBoss AS 5.1.0 it takes you to http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-5.1.0.GA/ which has various downloads marked as 5.1.0.GA